# How can i get an imagefrom the web with headers?

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

How can i get in c# an image as bitmapimage from an url and pass to it some headers? (not parameters, headers)

And also i found a simple solution but i couldn't understand why it was wrong, the problem is that:
WHen i get byte[] from the server i get the image with a lot of question marks, this appends i thinks because of a different text encoding, how can i fix the code so i can get successfully the image from c# with headers and visible to bitmap?

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert your image into a base64 encoded string and pass it to the headers.

```
using (Image image = Image.FromFile(Path))
{                 
    using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream())
    {
        image.Save(m, image.RawFormat);
        byte[] imageBytes = m.ToArray();

        // Convert byte[] to Base64 String
        string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
        return base64String;
    }                  
}
```

Then on the other side you can parse it and convert it back to an image:

```
public Image LoadImage()
{
    //data:image/png;base64,
    byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(YOUR_BASE64_ENCODED_STRING);

    Image image;
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
    {
        image = Image.FromStream(ms);
    }

    return image;
}
```

Comment: I mean to pass a header and then get the image without the ? (that means i have to change encoding)